# Angular Workspace "Projects" directory not showing in WebStorm

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli, webstorm

I have an Angular CLI Repo with two projects. In my root directory (pictured below in the project files) I have the projects folder and inside this folder is two folders with angular apps `application-A` and `application-B`.

If I open WebStorm at this root repo the project is created but does not include the `projects` directory so `application-a` and `application-b` are not included and all the files associated with these Angular apps are considered outside the project.

If I open WebStorm at the `projects/application-a` or `projects/application-b` level the project loads correctly within WebStorm but obviously I can only see one of the projects.

Is there not a way of indexing this repo from the root folder and including both applications within the Project? It's strange because as shown below the `projects` directory shows up in the Project Files but not the Project. I've tried removing the `.idea` folder, removing cache etc. and re-opening, this doesn't change anything. Thanks for your help.

[image: Project Files structure]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the picture, the root project `.idea` files are broken, the `.iml` file and/or `modules.xml` are either missing or corrupted, so all the project files are treated as non-project (note the yellow background). Deleting and re-creating `.idea` folder should help:

- close the project
- remove it from **Recent projects** list
- shut down the IDE
- delete the `.idea` folder and `.iml` file(s)
- restart, open the project root directory with **File > Open**